# How could i regard y variables as ordinal or nominal values in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning

There are y variables which are ordinal values or nominal values.

My question:
how could I make my model(sci-kit learn RandomForest or XGBoost etc.) regard y variables as nominal or ordinal values?

Is One-hot encoding or Converting y values into numerical values enough to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Please be specific about your "y" variables.

Comment: The y has four values : Good, Intermediate, Poor, Very Poor. But i want to test and compare two models using this y values such that one regards the y variables as ordinal values, the other regards the y variables as nominal values.